# Set Custom layout inside ListView as non-scrollable in android

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a `ListView` which contains a custom layout.

Each row of the list View look like this:

[image]

The row contains 2 `LinearLayouts`, one for Date and one for Progress details. The progress Details Layout consits of 2 `TextViews`(Heading and data below it) and 1 `Button` (View More).

When the user clicks '`View More`' button the data below the heading expands to 10-12 lines.

My problem is that when the `TextView` expands, a `scrollbar` comes at the edge and the user has to scroll to read. The width of the row does not change i.e the row does not expand.

I want the row width to expand so that the user does not have to scroll to read the text.

I did read a lot and have already tried the following options but they did not work

```
1. android:scrollbar="none"
2. View.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
3. View.setScrollContainer(false);
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Why don't you use **Expandable Listview**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a expandable `List View` such that the normal view of your list will have the image that you provided and on clicking that view it will expand to reveal the details that you wanted to show by clicking the `view more` option(in your image)

Here is a tut [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) for more info.

Comment: Could you add a little more to this answer? Something that would help others who come across this post would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks the link is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have to use exapanding listview animation for that you can use this lib for that
https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to work with this?

Comment: There is already examples inside that project https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations

Comment: It only shows the result, not the code example on how to use it.

Comment: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulation/expandablelistitems

Comment: No, the example is too complicated and half the things are missing for it. Plus there is no good documentation that I can refer to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LayoutParams and change the height programatically inside the listener for you Button.

LayoutParams should derive from the type of layout containing your LinearLayout. If for instance it is a RelativeLayout, it will look something like that:

```
int heightForRow = 100;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.height = heightForRow;
yourLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Please note that your LinearLayout must then be inside another layout (RelativeLayout in the example)

Comment: The height of the row is dynamic. I cannot set it to a fixed value.

Comment: I see. Maybe there is a way to get the height the TextView would like to get through its getMeasuredHeight() method and set this value to heightForRow? Not sure it would work but maybe you can try.
Hope it helps